# Nicer way to define `args` in the Thread constructor?

Tags: python, multithreading

When you create a thread you pass arguments as an iterable, typically a tuple like this:

```
import threading
import time

def countdown(secs):
    for second in range(secs, 0, -1):
        print(f"{second}!", end = " ")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Happy New Year!")

countdown_thread = threading.Thread(target=countdown, args=(5,))
countdown_thread.start()
countdown_thread.join()
```

I think the `(5,)` is syntactically gross and makes it harder to explain what's going on.  This line works just as well:

```
countdown_thread = threading.Thread(target=countdown, args=[5])
```

Is there any solid reason not to simply pass a list rather than a tuple to `Thread`? I don't want to lead people astray.

If there is no solid reason not to use a list, I'll just go with my opinion when I teach others.

Comment: `tuple` is immutable, but I doubt `Thread` would attempt to mutate `args` anyway. [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) technically say *"`args` is the argument tuple for the target invocation. Defaults to `()`."* but I assume they really just require a sequence, so for all practical purposes I don't see any reason why you can't pass `list` if you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

"args is the argument tuple for the target invocation. Defaults to ()." [Ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

The fact that it accepts a list is a bug that may or may not be fixed in future implementations. Or maybe they'll change the documentation. If you want to guarantee that your code will work in the future, you're best off sticking to what is guaranteed to work by the documention.

Comment: *"The fact that it accepts a list is a bug"* that is a strong claim, that I would argue is incorrect. I'd say the more correct statement is probably the docs use the word "tuple" when they should instead use "sequence" or something.

Comment: That's not a bug, that's just [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Comment: @wim.  The problem is that we have no idea of knowing if it's duck typing or not.  For example, there are various places in Numpy where a tuple as an index gives a different result than the identical list as an index.  There is nothing preventing the authors of Thread from doing the same in the future.  The documentation could have said "iterable"; it could have said "list or tuple"; it could have said "sequence".  It doesn't.  When in doubt, follow the documentation.

Comment: *There is nothing preventing the authors of Thread from doing the same in the future.* Yes there is: that would be a backwards compatibility break, which the core developers take very seriously. They'll take great care to avoid it, and if deemed absolutely necessary they would undergo a deprecation period where using an args list would cause `DeprecationWarning`. You're right about numpy, but it's an entirely different project from CPython, and numpy is not Pythonic in a myriad of ways- so their stance on duck typing is not really relevant here.

Comment: @wim.  I think we're going to have to just disagree here.  If the user had asked "I have some code that passes a list to arg=.  Should I fix it?"  I'd agree with you.  But the actual question is: "I don't like Python's singleton tuple syntax; should I write code according to the documentation anyway?  Should I teach other people that they don't need to follow the explicit documentation?"  To me the answers are clearly yes and no.  YMMV.

Comment: @FrankYellin The word “bug” invites some Very Strong Opinions(tm); however, I think your final comment is a better, more persuasive answer than your answer :)